# "how to get started making a game" faq link

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While offtopic, people [keep asking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80835/i-want-to-be-a-game-developres-please-help) questions in subject. I think that [Help Center > Asking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page can be improved a bit, by linking `how to get started making a game` to [this page](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html). During my personal experience in starting with gamedev I can say that this page is, at least, a very good starting point. Maybe even propagate it a little bit up (closer to `Ask Question` page), since such questions often asked by younger audience which is often impatient and/or unexperienced to read the FAQ.

Comment: Remember that downvotes here only mean people don't agree with the proposal.

Comment: UserGuide.SE.Com FTW !!! Have nooby guides and canned responses should just link to them when a mod shuts a question down with a default reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think essentially what you're suggesting is to create an answer for "How to get started". The reason that question is off topic here is because *there is no correct answer*. I think attempting to answer it with a single link is a bad idea.

I agree that Amit does some wonderful work, his tutorials are great. However, it's impossible for someone to cover all possible scenarios for getting started.

Further, most of the people who ask those questions, aren't reading anything anyway. They're just trying to find out how to get their question posted, regardless of the rules. It's not that they're reading the rules, then going against them (though that sometimes happens), they have a goal to post a question, and just "click-through" whatever's in the way. For this reason, I'm not sure that moving it up would be any more helpful or why this particular topic should be treated any differently that all the other off topic questions we have. Once we're moving all the off topic examples to the ask page, it's a cluttered mess, and we might be scaring away legitimate but unsure askers.